How can I make a heatmap with the exons of a gene with bam files coming from RNA-seq data in R-studio?
I´m new using R-studio and RNA-seq analysis but I´m trying to make a heatmap with the exons of a gene. My files are from a public database and first a convert the SRR file (from the GEO database) to bam file, After that, I wanted to make my heatmap in R-studio with that bam files but the R-studio console show me this messsage:
> # Crear el objeto DGEList
> dge <- DGEList(counts = matriz_conteo, genes = rownames(matriz_conteo))
Aviso:
In DGEList.default(counts = matriz_conteo, genes = rownames(matriz_conteo)) :
  At least one library size is zero
> 

After that, I had been trying to search what happen and apply the next codes to know the sizes of my files and if the position of the exons corresponds to the positions of the report exon positions in the reference genome that I used (GRCh38/hg38.p14). The size of my files is 0 in all of them and the position of my exons do not corresponds with the exon positions of the reference genome. I put the codes:
> dge$samples$lib.size
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0




> exones_dmd
GRangesList object of length 1:
$ENSG00000198947
GRanges object with 275 ranges and 2 metadata columns:
        seqnames            ranges strand |   exon_id       exon_name
           <Rle>         <IRanges>  <Rle> | <integer>     <character>
    [1]        X 31097677-31098183      - |   1011488 ENSE00001871364
    [2]        X 31119219-31121930      - |   1011489 ENSE00001478643
    [3]        X 31119219-31121930      - |   1011490 ENSE00003916589
    [4]        X 31119221-31121930      - |   1011491 ENSE00001880031
    [5]        X 31119222-31121930      - |   1011492 ENSE00003901420
    ...      ...               ...    ... .       ...             ...
  [271]        X 33211282-33211497      - |   1011761 ENSE00003920795
  [272]        X 33211282-33211519      - |   1011762 ENSE00003918256
  [273]        X 33211282-33211549      - |   1011763 ENSE00001899141
  [274]        X 33211282-33211554      - |   1011764 ENSE00001479071
  [275]        X 33339259-33339609      - |   1011765 ENSE00001478378
  -------
  seqinfo: 70 sequences (1 circular) from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths

>

